# How to know if JavaScript string.replace() did anything?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The `replace` function returns the new string with the replaces, but if there weren't any words to replace, then the original string is returned. Is there a way to know whether it actually replaced anything apart from comparing the result with the original string?

Comment: Why don't you want to compare the source string with the modified one?

Comment: This is another O(N) operation. Imagine I'm doing replaces on a 100KB strings.

Comment: Well, if the replacement occurred in the end of the string, then yes. But there is no O(1) answer for your question anyway. Either use match and then replace if needed, or do the replacement and then compare both strings.

Comment: @Alex - strictly speaking, "another O(N)" is still O(N).

Comment: Operating on 100kb strings in Javascript is in general a very very bad idea.

Comment: @jAndy it depends. Maybe he's using JavaScript on the server side

Comment: @stam, that is sad. I'm fond of how Perl does away with this returning  a flag of whether it did anything.

Comment: If Javascript uses string interning (and I can't find any reference to say whether it does) then comparison would be O(1), not O(n)

Comment: @StanislavYaglo, source can equals modified one. People want to verify that regexp works and to do replace in single pass.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A simple option is to check for matches before you replace:

```
var regex = /i/g;
var newStr = str;

var replaced = str.search(regex) >= 0;
if(replaced){
    newStr = newStr.replace(regex, '!');
}
```

If you don't want that either, you can abuse the `replace` callback to achieve that in a single pass:

```
var replaced = false;
var newStr = str.replace(/i/g, function(token){replaced = true; return '!';});
```

Comment: Note that function callbacks in String.replace are a Javascript 1.3 feature

Comment: @Alnitak - is that a problem? A quick check shows it was released in 1998, and implemented in IE 4! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions

Comment: not a problem, except that the Javascript reference page most often returned by Google (w3schools) fails to mention it.

Comment: @Kobi, your 'single pass' solution wont work in general, I've added an answer.

Comment: @Kobi how is the 2nd approach abusing the `replace` callback?

Comment: @protoEvangelion - I called this "abuse" because the callback is meant to calculate the result string, but here I use it to set a flag and use side-effects. I'm not using it as intended, hence "abuse".

Comment: Aww I see. So abuse in relation to function purity (no side effects). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the before and after strings is the easiest way to check if it did anything, there's no intrinsic support in `String.replace()`.

[contrived example of how '==' might fail deleted because it was wrong]

Comment: Why use `===` to test two strings for equlity?

Comment: Actually, `'0' == ''` is false, but `0 == ''` is true - you should be OK as long as you're dealing with strings. By the way, does `===` compare every character in the string, or does it check the reference? Many languages use string interning, but I'm not sure about JavaScript (and all implementations). If it does, this is definitely the best option.

Comment: @Kobi, good catch on the '0' vs 0 in my contrived example, but I think the point still stands that using '===' to compare strings is more reliable than using '=='

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can implement your own callback function that will set a flag and do the replacement. The `replacement` argument of `replace` can accept functions.

Comment: Yes, setting a flag from the callback is an interesting idea. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the only answer that doesn't involve searching the string multiple times. But apparently JS devs don't care about performance.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript `replace` is defected by design. Why? It has no compatibility with string replacement in callback.

For example:

```
"ab".replace(/(a)(b)/, "$1$2")
> "ab"
```

We want to verify that replace is done in single pass. I was imagine something like:

```
"ab".replace(/(a)(b)/, "$1$2", function replacing() { console.log('ok'); })
> "ab"
```

Real variant:

```
"ab".replace(/(a)(b)/, function replacing() {
  console.log('ok');
  return "$1$2";
})

> ok
> "$1$2"
```

But function `replacing` is designed to receive `$0, $1, $2, offset, string` and we have to fight with replacement "$1$2". The solution is:

```
"ab".replace(/(a)(b)/, function replacing() {
  console.log('ok');
  // arguments are $0, $1, ..., offset, string
  return Array.from(arguments).slice(1, -2)
  .reduce(function (pattern, match, index) {
    // '$1' from strings like '$11 $12' shouldn't be replaced.
    return pattern.replace(
      new RegExp("\\$" + (index + 1) + "(?=[^\\d]|$)", "g"),
      match
    );
  }, "$1$2");
});

> ok
> "ab"
```

This solution is not perfect. String replacement itself has its own WATs. For example:

```
"a".replace(/(a)/, "$01")
> "a"

"a".replace(/(a)/, "$001")
> "$001"
```

If you want to care about compatibility you have to read [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-45) and implement all its craziness.

Comment: actually, those "WATs" are defined in [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-45) and you don't need have to read nodejs source for this

Comment: @Zhegan, answer fixed. This is not a spec by the way. This is a bunch of incompatible craziness.

Answer (score 1):

If your replace has a different length from the searched text, you can check the length of the string before and after. I know, this is a partial response, valid only on a subset of the problem.

OR

You can do a search. If the search is successfull you do a replace on the substring starting with the found index and then recompose the string. This could be slower because you are generating 3 strings instead of 2.

```
var test = "Hellllo";
var index = test.search(/ll/);

if (index >= 0) {
    test = test.substr(0, index - 1) + test.substr(index).replace(/ll/g, "tt");
}

alert(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

While this will require multiple operations, using `.test()` may suffice:

```
const regex = /foo/;
const yourString = 'foo bar';

if (regex.test(yourString)) {
  console.log('yourString contains regex');
  // Go ahead and do whatever else you'd like.
}
```

[The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns true or false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: The question asks specifically for a single operation, `test` means that you still need to do the replacement.

Comment: The best option IMO

Answer (score 0):

With `indexOf` you can check wether a string contains another string.
Seems like you might want to use that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Do you suggest using `indexOf` to compare the original with the result of `replace`?

Comment: I suggest doing an `indexOf` before doing the replace. If the `indexOf` returns true, then you will know the replace will do anything.

Comment: The problem is that indexOf doesn't support regular expressions

Comment: but please don't.  If efficiency is the goal, then doing match followed by replace will surely be slower than '===' after the fact.

Comment: @AInitak, actually `search` might be faster than comparing if the regexp is simple and long enough.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at string.match() or string.search()

Comment: Do you suggest doing a `match` before `replace` to know if the latter will do anything?

Comment: no, since that means parsing the string against the regexp twice.  Just use '===' after - if the two strings are identical this is the fastest possible comparison.

Answer (score 0):

After doing any RegExp method, read `RegExp.lastMatch` property:

```
/^$/.test('');  //Clear RegExp.lastMatch first, Its value will be ''

'abcd'.replace(/bc/,'12');

if(RegExp.lastMatch !== '')
  console.log('has been replaced');
else
  console.log('not replaced');
```

Comment: Note that this is [deprecated and recommended not to be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#regexp), along with the other global state static properties on `RegExp`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a copy of the string to check if a replacement has been made. It can all be done in one pass. In most cases, I would it expect it to perform better than overriding the prototype or passing in a callback function.

```
const search = "foo";
const replace = "bar";
var str = "foo bar";

if (str === (str = str.replace(search, replace)))
{
    console.log("Not Changed");
}
else
{
    console.log("Changed");
}
// Logs: "Changed"

if (str === (str = str.replace(search, replace)))
{
    console.log("Not Changed");
}
else
{
    console.log("Changed");
}
// Logs: "Not Changed"
```

You probably shouldn't be using JavaScript to perform replacements on huge files. However, if you are, then I'd recommend at least doing some benchmarks to see which methods fastest.